# Instance of the class and invoke the method does not perform the same

Tags: c#, winforms, instance, invoke, libvlcsharp

Hey all I am trying to **add a function method** to **VideoControl.cs** so that I can call it from my **Form1.cs** button click. The code I am using is from a [**Github here.**](https://github.com/Benjiman1986/VlcPlayer)

Right now, in order to start a movie, I have to **right-click inside** the **videoControl1** on the form and select Load from the **ToolStripMenu**.

[image]

[image]

Doing that it goes into the **VideoControl.cs** **loadFileToolStripMenuItem_Click** function:

```
private void loadFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            Title = "Browse Video Files",
            CheckFileExists = true,
            CheckPathExists = true,
            DefaultExt = "ts",
            Filter = "All Media Files|*.MP4",
            FilterIndex = 2,
            RestoreDirectory = true,

            ReadOnlyChecked = true,
            ShowReadOnly = true
        };

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            m_fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            m_lastPlayedIsFile = true;
            Play(out string outMessage);
            
            if (pCallback != null)
            {
                foreach (IVideoControl p in pCallback)
                {
                    p.NotifyPlay(m_fileName, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So when I create a **public function** in **VideoControl.cs** like this so that I can just pass the video path to it without the need to select it form the browser select popup:

```
public static void testingVid(string theVideo)
    {
        m_fileName = theVideo;
        m_lastPlayedIsFile = true;
        Play(out string outMessage);

        if (pCallback != null)
        {
            foreach (IVideoControl p in pCallback)
            {
                p.NotifyPlay(m_fileName, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

And I am calling that like this from the **Form1.cs**:

```
VideoControl.testingVid(@"C:\Users\Admin\Videos\a_test_video.mp4");
```

I get the error on **VideoControl.testingVid** saying:

```
Error   CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'VideoControl.testingVid(string)'
```

When I **create an instance of the class and invoke the method** like this:

```
VideoControl VC = new VideoControl();
VC.testingVid(@"C:\Users\Admin\Videos\a_test_video.mp4");
```

It works (no errors) but it does not perform the same as if I did the right-click menu option. No error but it never plays.

Stepping through the code for both methods they **both** have the **same data** at the end (the video path and **p.NotifyPlay(m_fileName, true);** value of 1 in the loop).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why is it a `static` function, and why don't you just refer to your existing control 9rather than create a new unused hidden one), so `videoControl1.testingVid(PathHere);`

Comment: The GitHub repo you have linked has nothing to do with the code you have posted here, except it uses an old version of the VLC Player. You have a reference to `IVideoControl` here, which is a newer version. It's not exactly clear - since you have a custom implementation here - whether `VideoControl`  is a WinForms Custom Control or something else. If it is, you're creating a new instance of it, which is never added to an existing Parent container, so it's never initialized and never shown

Comment: If you create a new object and call the method on that, why would you expect to see a video play in the object already on your form? If you had a phone in your pocket, then went and got a new phone and opened YouTube on it, would you be surprised that there was no video playing on the phone in your pocket? Of course you wouldn't, because that would be magic. Why do you expect your code to perform magic? If you have an instance of your control type on your form and you expect it to play a video, call your method on that instance. Don't ignore the logic you've lived your whole life by so far.